# application_helper.rb error in ROR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I am stuck, cannot run my ROR app locally! 
I am getting the following error: missinghelpererror `application_helper.rb`

I have installed node.js and updated my PATH, which temporarily fixed this issue but again, I cannot get the app to launch. I have also changed my file paths to all lowercase /sites/code/demoapp as I saw that this could sometimes create an error! I have been struggling with this error for some time, any help would be terrific!

I even created a new page `home.html.erb` but when i visit this page, I get a similar error being:

`AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError` in PagesController#home

I am using rails -v 4.2.5.1

Comment: Post the error message as well as the first several lines following it in the stack trace. Let us know what your environment is like (OS in particular).

Comment: okay, I will post the stack trace tonight -- I am using W10